# Trying get my redux form results to render within the same component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

I am trying use a redux form to pass a field into a action creator that hits an api with that field result. The results should be sent back to that same component and render under the search input field. here is my action creator

```
export function getStock({ticker_symbol}){

    console.log(ticker_symbol)
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios.get(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=${ticker_symbol}&interval=1min&apikey=5QP2C2R2YCZ71HDB&datatype=json`, {
            headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem('token')}
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data["Time Series (1min)"])
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_STOCK,
                    payload: res.data
                })
            }).catch(res => {
                dispatch(authError(res.error))
            });

    }
}
```

here is the reducer

```
import {
    FETCH_MESSAGE,
    GET_STOCK   
} from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = {}, action){
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_MESSAGE:
         return {...state, message: action.payload};
        case GET_STOCK:
        return {...state, stock: action.payload,
                          stockDataLoaded: false};
    }

    return state;
}
```

here is the component that has the form and is suppose to get the rendering information. The console logs are getting me the correct data.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class Feature extends Component{
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchMessage();

    }
    handleFormSubmit({ ticker_symbol }){
        console.log( ticker_symbol );
        this.props.getStock({ticker_symbol});
    }
    render(){
        const { handleSubmit, fields: { ticker_symbol }} = this.props;
        return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
            <fieldset className="form-group">
                <label> Ticker Symbol: </label>
                <input {...ticker_symbol} className="form-control" />
             </fieldset>
             <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary"> Get Quote </button>
        </form>
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log(state);
    return { message: state.stock.message, 
    stock: state.stock.stock};
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'getstock',
    fields: ['ticker_symbol']
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(Feature);
```

Here is a screenshot of the page/console

[image: THE CONSOLE LOG SHOWS AFTER SEARCH IS SUCCESSFUL]

I want the results to appear under the ticker symbol

Comment: This all looks fine, what problem are you having?

Comment: every time I try to put state.state.stock in the empty <h1> </h1> tags in the component, it gives me an error. I guess because there is no state until the results come back. I am a bit new to redux, so not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your comment;

Any component that relies on it's state needs to initialize the state attribute using the `getInitialState` lifecycle hook, as such;

```
getInitialState() {
    return {

    };
}
```

You can leave it entirely empty if you wish to merely initialize the state object, or you can populate it with default starting values.

Comment: ```
   componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchMessage();

    }
```
do i put the get initial sate above the component will mount, or in it? I juggled it around a bit and still cant get it.

Comment: `getInitialState` is a lifecycle hook.  It should be applied to the component the same way as you did for `componentWillMount` (which is another lifecycle hook).  Whether it is above or below other hooks is irrelevant, but definitely not inside.

Comment: sorry I mean replace willmount not inside of willmount. when i console mapStateToProps() of state.stock.stock, i get the object I am looking for. Before the form is submitted that item is undefined or doesnt exist. Am i suppose to put that in get initial state and set it to null? I am not sure exactly what I am suppose to put in there.

Comment: Simply setting it to null should be enough.